# Fastlane scan failing randomly when testing SPM packages - IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6

Tags: ios, fastlane, swift-package-manager

I have a project that consists of several SPM packages. I'm using Fastlane to perform tests on each of those packages, like so

```
lane :tests do
  TEST_PACKAGES.each { |package|
    single_test(package: package, devices: TEST_DEVICES)
  }
end

lane :single_test do |options|
  package = options[:package]
  devices = options[:devices]
  scan(
      package_path: package,
      scheme: package,
      devices: devices,
      output_directory: './' + package  + '/' + TEST_OUTPUT_DIR,
      buildlog_path: TEST_BUILDLOG_PATH,
      derived_data_path: DERIVED_DATA_PATH,
      code_coverage: true,
      result_bundle: true,
      fail_build: false,
      clean: true,
      configuration: "Debug"
    )     
end
```

The problem is that this will randomly fail - sometimes on first package, sometimes on second, and sometimes further, with errors similar to this one:

> Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6 "Cannot open "swift-custom-dump" as a "Swift Package Proxy" because it is already open as a "Swift User Managed Package Folder"."

Several errors like that appear, referring to dependencies used by the specific package.

There is no consistency in this behaviour, as simply calling `fastlane tests` again, without any changes, will result in tests failing for different package.

What might be the cause?

Comment: Seems like you have the same problem with derived data location, see the same discussion here https://forums.swift.org/t/xcode-and-swift-package-manager/44704

Comment: Seen that, not related. Also, I think if it was an issue witch cache, the problem would be consistent, failing always at the same step. Right now it can fail at first package, or go through 5-6 packages before failing. There's no pattern to it.

Comment: @mag_zbc did you find any solution ? I think I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem in Xcode14, but it was due to a framework resource bundle code-sign issue.
If you're using CocoaPods, please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11402)